# Why do all Object IDs in MongoDB start with the number 5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I've noticed that all MongoDB ids that have been generated in my webapp so far start with the number 5.  For example, 54fb5359b903f0340d000006 and  54fca4664679861c17000002.  Why is that the case?

Comment: now they all start with 6! Someday you can tell your kids you are old enough to remember when object IDs started with a 5. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mongo uses a specific algorithm to generate the IDs based on several underlying factors.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

For example, it looks like the first few bytes are a timestamp, something which will have the same first digit for quite some time.

Comment: Do you know the exact algo?  Because the current epoch time is 1425937474 and that doesn't start with a 5.

Comment: Sure, it is outputted as hex. 1425937474 in hex is 54FE1442